# Extract text within HTML <br> tags JSOUP

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am writing a JAVA program to extract HTML data for a project.
This is the HTML code

```
 <td align="left" valign="top" class="style3">
        PC / Van<br>$14 (Mon-Fri, excl PH)
        <br>
        $18 (Sat, Sun & PH)<br><br>$70/Day(Mon-Fri, excl PH: Entry - 24:00)   
        <br>
        $100/day (Sat, Sun & PH: Entry - 24:00)
 </td></tr>
```

The following is my JAVA code for extraction.

```
 String connect1 = url1.toString();
 Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(connect1).get();


        // get all links
        Elements type1 = doc1.select("[class=\"style3\"]");     

        int size = type1.size();

            try {       
                String text =type1.first.text();
                System.out.println(text);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

The output I get is

```
PC / Van$14 (Mon-Fri, excl PH)$18 (Sat, Sun & PH)$70/Day(Mon-Fri, excl PH: Entry - 24:00)$100/day (Sat, Sun & PH: Entry - 24:00)
```

How can I split them from the < br > tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can replace all `<br>` labels to `\n` symbol,the code example is shown below:

```
Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse(s);
Elements type1 = doc1.select("[class=\"style3\"]");
try {       
    String text =type1.first().html();
    text = text.replaceAll("<br>", "\n");
    System.out.println(text);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or split the text to string array with `<br>` label

```
Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse(s);
Elements type1 = doc1.select("[class=\"style3\"]");
try {       
    String text =type1.first().html();
    String[] textSplitResult = text.split("<br>");
    if (null != textSplitResult) {
         for (String t : textSplitResult) {
             System.out.println(t);
         }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or use java8 lambda to output result

```
String text =type1.first().html();
String[] textSplitResult = text.split("<br>");
if (null != textSplitResult) {
    Arrays.stream(textSplitResult).peek((x) -> System.out.println(x)).count();
    //or Arrays.stream(textSplitResult).peek(System.out::println).count();
}
```

The executing result:

```
PC / Van
$14 (Mon-Fri, excl PH)
$18 (Sat, Sun &amp; PH)

$70/Day(Mon-Fri, excl PH: Entry - 24:00)
$100/day (Sat, Sun &amp; PH: Entry - 24:00)
```

Comment: It would have been nice if one answer focused on/stressed the underlying problem that `Element.text()` only returns the text contained in the element (dropping all HTML tags like `<br>`), while `Element.html()` retains them and thus allows splitting at `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

According to this question

[How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

```
String text =type1.first.text();

String[] textArr = text.split("<br>");
```

Comment: this doesn't work as the result of `.text()` doesn't contain any `<br>` tags, see comment to the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31870306/3944322).